# SharePoint designer string replace function

Tags: sharepoint, string, sharepoint-designer

[SharePoint Designer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_Designer) does not support the replace function directly.

What would be a function or call Template for this? I want to replace "-Y" with "Yes" and "-N" with "NO" in a string. E.g.:

> Sample-Y, Sample1-N

Result as:

> Sample Yes Sample1 No

Comment: Please explain how are you modifying and where you have to modify.
It would be better if you could provide some code snippet.
I think you can use javascript replace function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do and what part of SharePoint Designer you are using, but if you are talking about workflows then checkout the Workflow Power Pack, which allows you to embed any C# or VB code inside your workflow. This makes the usual string manipulation functionality very easy.

An example of string manipulation functionality can be found [here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/sharepoint-workflow-power-pack-user.html).

Disclaimer, I worked on this product and it is fab ;-)